# How to get started with Scrapy Web Service?

Tags: web-services, scrapy

I have been using Scrapy for a long time now and I must say I am in love with it. Recently, I got to know about [Scrapy Web Service](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/webservice.html). But I am unable to figure out how it works. Or how can I use it to monitor my current spiders.

Looking for a documentation or getting started guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, [that document you've linked](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/webservice.html) is the closest thing to a guide there is. It doesn't do much hand-holding but should be enough to get you going -- it even comes with [an example client script](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/webservice.html#example-of-web-service-client).

In short, [the web service is enabled by default](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/webservice.html#std:setting-WEBSERVICE_ENABLED), and it answers to HTTP requests using the [JSON RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) protocol for remote calls.

You can try it out after starting `scrapy shell` inside a Scrapy project, point your browser to: http://localhost:6080. You should see a page showing the available resources:

```
{"resources": ["enginestatus", "stats", "crawler"]}
```

From this point onwards, you will advance knowing a bit more of [JSON RPC Version 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC#Version_2.0), to construct the proper calls -- here is an example using `requests`:

```
>>> import requests, json
>>> jsonrpc_call = {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'list', 'params': [], 'id': 1}
>>> resource = 'http://localhost:6080/crawler/spiders'
>>> requests.post(resource, data=json.dumps(jsonrpc_call)).json()
{u'id': 1, u'jsonrpc': u'2.0', u'result': [u'spider1', u'spider2']}
```

**IMPORTANT:** You should know that this JSON RPC service has been extracted out from Scrapy for the next release, and now lives as a separate project: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy-jsonrpc. So, be prepared when upgrading to Scrapy 1.0. ;)

Comment: You may simplify and improve the example above to get more convinient usage of `requests` library - `requests.post(resource, json=jsonrpc_call).json()`. See more [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)!